# How to accurately resize nested elements with ems and font-size percentage?

Tags: javascript, css, font-size, percentage

I have a carousel with textboxes for each image, and my client (who knows nothing about HTML) edits the textboxes using a WYSIWYG text editor.  The resulting output is akin to your worst nightmares; something like:

```
<div class="carousel-text-container">
<span style="font-size:18pt;">
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">
         Lorem 
         <span style="font-size:15pt;">Dolor</span>
     </span>
    Ipsum
    <span style="font-size:19pt;">
         <span>&nbsp;</span>
         <span>Sit<span>Amet</span></span>
    </span>
</span>
</div>
```

This site has to be displayed at 3 different sizes to accomodate smaller monitors, so I have been using CSS media queries to resize the site.

Now I am having trouble resizing the text inside the textbox correctly.  I have tried using `jQuery.fn.css` to get the font size of each element in `px`, and then convert it to `em`.  Then, by setting a `font-size:x%` sort of declaration on `.carousel-text-container`, I hoped that that would resize everything properly.

Unfortunately, there seems to be a recursive nature with how font-size is applied in ems.  That is, `.example` is not resized properly in the following because its parent is also influencing it

```
<span style="font-size:2em;">
    Something
    <span class="example" style="font-size:1.5em;">Else</span>
</span>
```

How can I resize everything reliably and precisely such I can achieve a true percentage of my original font size, margin, padding, line-height, etc. for all the children of `.carousel-text-container`?

Right now, I'm at the point of imagining up some sort of recursive JavaScript function:

```
var carouselTextBoxEl;
function resizeCarouselTextBox () {
    // some example numbers thrown in
    var newWidthRatio = .8,
    function resizeCarouselTextBoxEl (el, nestedLevelNum) {
        nestedLevelNum = nestedLevelNum || 1;
            
        var childElFontSizePxStr = parseFloat(el.css('font-size')), // 16.2984392, for example
            // calculate new font size based on
            // width ratio of original size site to new size,
            // and do something with nestedLevelNum... what's the math with that?
            newChildElFontSizePxStr = childElFontSizePxStr * newWidthRatio,
            // get children of el, if any
            elChildrenEls = el.children(),
            i = elChildrenEls.length;
            
            el.css('font-size', newChildElFontSizePxStr + 'em');               
            while (--i >= 0) {
                resizeCarouselTextBoxEl(elChildrenEls[i], nestedLevelNum + 1);    
            }

    }
    
    carouselTextBoxEl.children().each(function () {
        resizeCarouselTextBoxEl($(this)
    });    
}
onSmallerScreen(resizeCarouselTextBox);
```

UPDATE:  I am letting the client take advantage of resizing certain words to use as headings and such, so I cannot simply just set everything to a single font size.

Just a thought:  would it be possible to place inside an HTML5 canvas and take a snapshot and/or resize that way?

Answer (score 0):

This is a nature of CSS (**Cascading** Style Sheets) that all child elements inherit styles of their parents :)

I would use jQuery to dynamically select all child elements of the given container and change their font size:

```
$('.carousel-text-container').find('*').css('font-size', '14px');
```

Alternatively, you can remove font size so that all child elements will use font size declared  for `.carousel-text-container` class:

```
$('.carousel-text-container').find('*').css('font-size', '');
```